# bridge Vs Factless Fact

Tags: data-modeling, dimensional-modeling

Using snowflake database, Brokerage industry , Plan Dim stores contract details about stock plan services between the service provider and Client org, while Custody Account Dim stores Custody accounts held by a client
`Plan Dim: Plan Dim Key (Surrogate Key) + Plan Nbr (Natural Key) Custody Account Dim: Custody Account Dim Key (Surrogate Key) + Custody Account Nbr (Natural Key)`

My requirement is to build a structure to associate Plan Dim and Custody account Dim (many-to-many relation). Currently the business will use this as stand alone, but have no visibility on how this will be used in any other Facts.

1. First, I am trying to decide between following structures whether the relation has to be built using Dim Keys or Natural Keys. My understanding is, if the business requires to store history of Dimension relationships, then use Option 1 below. The challenge is, every time a new Dim key is generated in parent Dimension, I need to relate the new Dim Keys in the relationship table and Keep adding.

However If the business requires to store only latest Dim Key relationship then I can use Option 2 or Option 3

Option 1: Plan Dim Key - Custody Account Dim Key - Plan Nbr - Custody Acct Number
OR
Option 2: Latest Plan Dim Key - Latest Custody Account Dim Key - Plan Nbr - Custody Acct Number-
Or
Option 3: Plan Nbr - Custody Acct Number

2)Second, I am trying to decide between a Bridge Table or Factless Fact? These both look similar but from my limited knowledge Bridge will have a Same Bridge group Key to group multiple relationships and use the Group Key in Other Facts. However a Date field is not mandatory.  While Factless Fact will have a Date Field on it mandatorily and used to create a daily snapshot of Dim Key relationships and is the end point (ie this factless fact will not be used in other Facts unlike a Bridge which will be used on other Facts)

Given the above details, especially since Business is unsure if this relationship will be used in other Facts in future, what would be the best answer to my above two questions? Also if you have a  decision tree of when to use Bridge Vs Factless Fact, that would be very helpful

Thanks in Advance
Sunny

Comment: In a dimensional model you relate dimensions via facts

Comment: Is that always true? Bridge can also relate Dimensions right? Sorry, trying to understand when to use what :-)

Comment: You query facts and the dimensions associated to them - so you should always start with your fact table and build out from there. Whether there is a specific use case that also needs a bridge table doesn't negate the need for a fact table. While there may be (rare) circumstances where a fact table is not appropriate, I would always start with the fact table and prove why it won't work - rather than starting with a "custom" approach to the design